# How to scale correctly with an offset (ref0) when using bounds in OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I am trying to include some ref0= scaling in my optimization problem, but I keep getting a bounds error: `ValueError: SLSQP Error: lb > ub in bounds True, False.`. Without ref0= scaling the optimization runs fine. Taking the paraboloid optimization example from the docs (with slight modifications to get larger magnitudes in the values):

```
import openmdao.api as om

# build the model
prob = om.Problem()

prob.model.add_subsystem('paraboloid', om.ExecComp('f = (x-10)**2 + x*y + (y+40)**2 - 3'))

# setup the optimization
prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.model.add_design_var('paraboloid.x', lower=20, upper=60, ref=10, ref0=40)
prob.model.add_design_var('paraboloid.y', lower=-100, upper=50, ref=10)
prob.model.add_objective('paraboloid.f')

prob.setup()

# Set initial values.
prob.set_val('paraboloid.x', 40)
prob.set_val('paraboloid.y', -4.0)

# run the optimization
prob.run_driver()

# minimum value
print(prob.get_val('paraboloid.f'))

# location of the minimum
print(prob.get_val('paraboloid.x'))
print(prob.get_val('paraboloid.y'))
```

Now of course it may be unnecessary for this simple problem to add such scaling, but it serves the purpose of recreating the problem. Adding ref0=40 to the 'paraboloid.x' design var will cause the bounds error. How can/should I correctly setup the bounds and scale factors in order for the optimizer to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref0` and `ref` specify those values which the optimizer sees as 0 and 1, respectively.  When you set `ref0 > ref`, you're essentially flipping the axis of that variable, as far as the optimizer is aware.

The scaling is then applied to your `lower` and `upper` bounds.  Because the axis is flipped, `upper` is now less than `lower` and the optimizer is unhappy.

In this case the correct behavior can be obtained by swapping the values of `lower` and `upper`, although I'd argue that providing `ref > ref0` is more logical.